# How to log transform in R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I have a dataset which consist of 10 k rows
I am asked to perform log transform on the column, Number using the function, log function in R. I also want to ask on how does  log transform remove skewness based on the data below? Does log transform remove data from the column?

```
Number
5
6
20
60
90
20
30
10
10
40
50
99
23
25
10
900
885
300
200
100
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
df <- data.frame(Number = seq(5))
log(df, base = 10)
#>      Number
#> 1 0.0000000
#> 2 0.3010300
#> 3 0.4771213
#> 4 0.6020600
#> 5 0.6989700
log(df) # natural ln
#>      Number
#> 1 0.0000000
#> 2 0.6931472
#> 3 1.0986123
#> 4 1.3862944
#> 5 1.6094379
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>